# What are the analogous matrix operations of graph union and intersection operations?

Tags: graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I know that a graph can be represented by its adjacency matrix. Graph union and graph intersection are two important basic operations in graph theory. Working with graphs and their operations is good to visualise certain relations or social networking etc., but when it comes to computational (programming) part, it becomes difficult to feed the graphs directly into our systems (computers). Hence it often requires to be converted into corresponding matrix form. Suppose, in case i am coverting the matrices into corresponding adjacency matrices,

> What are possible analogous matrix operations of  graph union and graph intersection operations?

**Note that the graph i am talking about is simple and undirected**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not very natural operations from the point of view of linear algebra, but we can define them on matrices (and compute them in MATLAB or whatever).

- For the intersection of two graphs with adjacency matrices $A$ and $B$, we take the element-wise $\min$ of their entries: that is, the $(i,j)$-th entry of the result should be  $$\min(A,B)_{ij} = \min(A_{ij}, B_{ij}).$$
- For the union of two graphs, we take the element-wise $\max$ of their entries.

For example, if I have the graphs

```
1 -- 2 -- 3               1 -- 3 -- 2
```

then their adjacency matrices are, respectively,
$$
   A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \qquad B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The min and the max will be
$$
   \min(A,B) = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \qquad \max(A,B) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and these are the intersection and the union of the two graphs.

Comment: Yes, this is true for the matrices of same dimensions. But it will not be true in the general case.

Comment: Well, how are you going to take the intersection or union of two graphs with different vertex sets? That isn't defined either, so you don't have an operation that needs to be extended to matrices.

Comment: Well, if we have any two undirected graphs of disjoint vertex sets, then their union graph will be a disconnected  graph containing the union of their  vertex sets, and their intersection graph will be the one that contains only those common vertices (of the given graphs). So, i think in general, the analogous matrix operations of graph union and intersection will be a non conventional one.

Comment: **Correction:** Intersection of two graphs with disjoint vertex sets will be an empty graph.

Comment: That's an unusual definition to make, but in that case you should first insert zero rows and columns into the adjacency matrices to give the graph the same vertex set.

Comment: Inserting zero rows and columns seems good idea to work with this intuition, and in line with this intuition, i think we can delete zero rows and zero columns too. Isn't? Thank you.

Comment: Deleting zero rows and columns corresponds to deleting isolated vertices. Whether or not you need to track those depends on what you're doing with the graphs.